# Podspec - sourcing files using relative path with http

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, cocoapods, podspec

I'm writing a **podspec** and need to use relative path for fetching files using http, example:

```
 s.source = { :http => "file://#{__myDir__}/gitFolder/zipfile.zip"}
```

`{__myDir__}` must be relative otherwise there will be changes in our git repository every time a team member pushes a change. How can I make the path relative?

Example:
When I run pod install the generated file will change to:

```
s.source = { :http => "file://myComputer/myName/myPath/gitFolder/zipfile.zip"}
```

and when another team member runs it, it changes to:

```
s.source = { :http => "file://hisComputer/hisName/hisPath/gitFolder/zipfile.zip"}
```

Comment: You can do it in the `Podfile` instead of the podspec: `pod 'MyPod', :path => '..'`